# Devise + Facebook Omniauth Error on redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth, facebook-authentication

I am using devise, omniauth & facebook-omniauth for my Rails 3.1 app. After authentication I wanted to redirect the user to the page was viewing. I have used the following code for the same:

```
def facebook
@user = Spree::User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)
if @user.persisted?
flash[:notice] = "Yipee! You were successfully authorized from your Facebook account!!"
sign_in @user, :event => :authentication
redirect_to request.referrer
end
```

This gives me the following error only at the time of user creation:

```
ActionController::ActionControllerError in Spree::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook
Cannot redirect to nil!
```

The following times when the user has already been created, no errors are shown during & after log in.

How do you suggest I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can overwrite the functions for sign in/ sign up path in your application controller:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  credit_path 
  return request.env['omniauth.origin'] || session[:return_to] 
end 

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  return request.env['omniauth.origin'] || session[:return_to]
end
```

use sessions to store the current path in the path that you want them to go to: `session[:return_to] = request.url` #store current location

or you create a method that will always be called once they go to a path and store that location. watch out for a giant loop redirection when you do that though.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me I just made a slight change in my in line with what you suggested and it worked:
redirect_to request.referrer||request.env['omniauth.origin']